# Is my translation of "こちらから訊くより先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた" correct?

Tags: translation, meaning

While working on a translation for the following Japanese sentence, my brain inexplicably spits out a translation without giving me a reason for each translated segment.

> こちらから訊くより先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。

When I reflected on my/its reasoning, it gives me the following as its reasons for translating to produce the English sentence below.

> (My brain's reasoning after the fact): 'the Japanese comma and the English comma are mostly the same in terms of placement. This word goes here, here, that one over there, here, and...'
>
> こちらから訊くより先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。
>
> Translation:
>
> From me asking her directly, she brings down her voice back to a similar mummer.

Question is, is my brain's random, possibly correct translation accurate, given the context of the 1st person POV character talking to a girl with the following dialogue?

> POV: 「君は……」
>
> Girl: [名前なら、ないわ]
>
> こちらから訊くより先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 先に means "before" in this context. See: [What is the difference between 前に and 先に when expressing order of events?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57147/5010)
- 返る is an intransitive verb, whose subject is 声.
- 低く呟くような modifies 声 (i.e., "a low and murmur-like voice"). This 声 refers to what she said, "名前なら、ないわ". You should review the basic grammar of ような...

> こちらから訊くより先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。
>   Before I asked (her name), a low murmur returned (from her).